# Accessing shared network folders in Erlang/Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

Has something changed with the way Erlang 20/ Elixir 1.5 handle file paths to network shared folders? In my Elixir app running on a Windows server, I used to be able to refer to file paths that include virtual drive names (e.g., V:) which is mapped to shared network folders (eg., \server1\shared_folder), but after upgrading Erlang/Elixir recently (it could be a coincidence) it doesn't seem to recognize these file paths.

For instance, `Monitor.start_link(dirs: ["C:/data/"])` works, but `Monitor.start_link(dirs: ["V:/data/"]` doesn't.

In case it helps, here is the Monitor module.

```
defmodule FinReporting.Monitor do

    use GenServer
    alias FinReporting.Repo
    alias FinReporting.AppState

    def start_link(args) do
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args)
    end

    def init(args) do
        {:ok, watcher_pid} = FileSystem.start_link(args)
        FileSystem.subscribe(watcher_pid)
        IO.inspect(watcher_pid, label: "Watcher PID")
        {:ok, %{watcher_pid: watcher_pid}}

    end

    def handle_info({:file_event, watcher_pid, {path, events}}, 
            %{watcher_pid: watcher_pid}=state) do

        callback(path, events)
        {:noreply, state}
    end

    def handle_info({:file_event, watcher_pid, :stop},
            %{watcher_pid: watcher_pid}=state) do
       callback(:stop)
        {:noreply, state}
    end

#  The callback runs a python module using erlport
    def callback(:stop) do
        IO.puts "STOP"
    end

    def callback(file_path, events) do
        case {file_path, events} do
            {"e:\\reporting_temp\\data\\mls_alltrans\\AllTrans - All MLS_postdate.txt", [:modified]} -> 

                affix = File.stat!(file_path).mtime
                        |> :calendar.universal_time_to_local_time
                        |> Ecto.DateTime.from_erl()
                        |> Calendar.Strftime.strftime!("%b %d (%a) %l:%M %P")

                result = AppState.changeset(%AppState{}, %{key: "alltrans_filechange_" <> affix, value: "downloaded"})
                    |> Repo.insert

                case result do
                    {:ok, struct} -> 
                        IO.inspect("inserted successfully")
                        py_mls_upload()
                    {:error, changeset} -> IO.inspect("insert failed")

                end

           { _ , _ } -> 
               IO.inspect {file_path, events, "irrelevant"}
        end
    end

    defp py_mls_upload do
        {:ok, pp} = :python.start([{:python_path, to_char_list(Path.expand("lib/python_scripts"))}, {:python, 'python'}])
        :python.call(pp, :mlsupload, :run, [])
    end

end
```

Comment: Does `"C:\\data\\"` work?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code behind the `Monitor.start_link` function call in this code? Know what function is actually using the path will be helpful.

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, that works too. It doesn't seem to matter whether it's one or two slashes.

Comment: @Stratus3D Please see the module definition updated above. E: and C: are both local drives.

Comment: I see the argument gets passed to `FileSystem.start_link`, that's likely where the issue is. Is that module code you wrote or is that an existing library?

Comment: It's an existing library. https://github.com/falood/file_system